# Conceptual Model of Contactless Cards

Tags: interaction-design, design, cards, mental-models, concept

Contactless card is a card for limited value transactions that one doesn't need to add a PIN on a POS, just tap on it, that's why they are also known as "tap-and-go" cards. ([More info](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/110716/what-are-contactless-cards-and-how-safe-are-they.asp))

On my research, I have analyzed what is the idea that people have on: information sent between the card and card reader, the maximum amount one can pay with this type of cards, how many times one can use this type of card per day, if there are other alternatives (one example: smartphones), how do this last example works, what happens if I have multiple contactless cards in a wallet and what happens when one card is stolen.

What are some examples of conceptual models or user flow for this? How can I design a better conceptual model that would allow users to develop a better mental model of contactless cards (assuming that this is a desirable goal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inquired some people on the topic and accordingly to their mental model it is clear that the conceptual model has problems when it comes to security: unless we have pockets that would not let information out, by being covered with aluminium foil (for example), there is always a chance of being hacked, which causes lack of trust in the system.

In my opinion, the conceptual model could take in consideration another validation method.
Considering that the focus of this kind of technology is the speed when it comes to the transactions, biometrics could be a way to solve this issue. By implementing a confirmation based on, for example, finger prints, the transactions will be equally fast, but safer.

This change in the conceptual model would give the user a sense of security changing their mental model.
Also, it could be a way to increase the transaction limits that this type of cards are usually associated with.